# UIViewController with UITableView crashing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, crash

I've got an UIViewController with a UITableView inside. I implemented everything programmatically but the application crashes or doesn't display the data in the array.
Here's my sample code:

**uWDataResumeController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface uWDataResumeController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *dataForMyTable2;
    UITableView *myDataTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myDataTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataForMyTable2;

@end
```

***uWDataResumeController***

```
#import "uWDataResumeController.h"
@implementation uWDataResumeController
@synthesize myDataTable, dataForMyTable2;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [dataForMyTable2 release];
    [myDataTable release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    myDataTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    myDataTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    myDataTable.rowHeight = 86;
    myDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myDataTable.delegate = self;
    myDataTable.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myDataTable];
    [myDataTable release];
    dataForMyTable2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    [myDataTable reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section                 
    return [dataForMyTable2 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataForMyTable2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

***EDIT:*** Added stacktrace

The nice thing is that I don't get a stacktrace as usual, but if I type in gdb backtrace i get

```
#0  0x016a7fd7 in CALayerGetDelegate ()
#1  0x0004c76e in -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] ()
#2  0x0004304e in -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] ()
#3  0x000430f2 in -[UIView(Geometry) hitTest:withEvent:] ()
#4  0x0003c6b6 in +[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:pathIndex:forEvent:] ()
#5  0x0001c709 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#6  0x00ffa992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#7  0x00da2944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x00d02cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#9  0x00cfff83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x00cff840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x00cff761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x00ff91c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x00ff9289 in GSEventRun ()
#14 0x00021c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x00002039 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff064) at main.m:14
```

Comment: could you give us some error details? stack trace?  My guess is that you are trying to access an element of the array that doesnt exist.  but Ill need to see errors to confirm.

Comment: You should put an autorelease in your `- (void)loadView...` for your initialized view, self.view = XXX will retain the instance. But this is not the cause for your crash. Please show us the stacktrace and the console output.

Comment: Added stacktrace to the first post

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a temp variable:
Instead of:

```
    myDataTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds      
     style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Do this:

```
UITableView *TEMPDataTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

and then instead of:

```
  [self.view addSubview:myDataTable];
  [myDataTable release];
  dataForMyTable2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
  [myDataTable reloadData];
```

Do this:

```
[self.view addSubview:TEMPDataTable];
self.myDataTable=TEMPDataTable;
[TEMPDataTable release];
dataForMyTable2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
[myDataTable reloadData];
```

Comment: Also, I'm wondering whether you should use   self.dataForMyTable2 =  to make sure that this is retained.  In your numberOfRowsInSection:  add NSLog(@"row count is %d",[dataForMyTable2 count]);

Comment: Where does it crash - what line?  As soon as it crashes, type "bt" in the debugger - at the (GDB) prompt.  That will generate a back trace and tell you where it crashed.  Post THAT please.

Comment: Here's the new back trace with your suggestion [link](http://pastebin.com/1Bthi1fG)

Comment: Ok, you've got a zombie table (really!).  objc_msgSend () means you're sending a message to a deallocated (zombie) instance. (Search SO for NSZombieEnabled for how to turn this on.)  This means your myDataTable is not yet available.  It's crashing on your "reloadData" call.  So try moving this reloadData to viewDidAppear, or leave it out altogether - the table should load itself when it's first displayed.

Comment: I removed reloadData, but nothing changes. Here's NSZombie Log '2011-05-05 22:14:15.486 Tableviewtest[4911:207] *** -[uWDataResumeController numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e306e0' same stacktrace

Comment: Looks like your view controller has been deallocated... how are you presenting uWDataResumeController?

Comment: I just cleaned the project, rebuilt it and for some odd reason, even with my original code now it works! I can't reproduce the crash anymore..... That's strange!

Comment: I uploaded the project if someone wants to see the whole code [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?fwbaleta3jr7lla) but it isn't necessary, because now it works.

Answer (score 0):

i've copied your code into a new project and it works fine for me as is.

I thought it may be the tableview being released twice, but I can't replicate the crash.